# How to use nested maps in thymeleaf?

Tags: hashmap, thymeleaf

I have created a map
`Map<String, Map<Integer,String>>`
 in DTO and accessing it in html using thymeleaf as below:

```
<div class="popupui" th:each="lang,st : ${session.languages}" >                        
< label th:text="#{'language.label.' + ${lang.languageName} }" >English  < /label>
<input type="text"
    th:field="*{languageMap['answerAlternative'][${st.count}]}"
    th:id="'name-' + ${lang.languageId}" class="languageId"/><a
    th:class="'flag-' + ${lang.languageName}" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

A processingException is coming at `th:field="*{languageMap['answerAlternative'][${st.count}]}"`

i have also tested the above th:field with:

```
<input type="text" 
 th:field="*{languageMap[ __${'answerAlternative'}__][__${st.count}__]}"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the Thymeleaf docs,

> Variable expressions not only can be written in ${...} expressions, but also in *{...} ones.
>
> There is an important difference, though: the asterisk syntax evaluates expressions on selected objects rather than on the whole context variables map.

Are you perhaps missing the selection `th:object="yourDTO"` on a div that's the parent of the "popupui" div in question for you to be able to use `*{...}`

Further, if you intend to display the values from the "language map" shouldn't you rather be using

`th:value="*{languageMap['answerAlternative'][st.count]}"`

In any case, if you have the selection as above then the below should work

`th:field="*{languageMap['answerAlternative'][st.count]}"`

Thymeleaf Reference:

[4.3 Expressions on selections (asterisk syntax)](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Using-Thymeleaf.html#expressions-on-selections-asterisk-syntax)